# How to reference Exported value in cloudformation template

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am using Outputs in cloudformation to Export some resources and using it in another template.

In my template.yaml I've this defined.

```
Outputs:
  MyECSTaskRole:
    Value: !GetAtt ECSTaskRole.Arn
    Export:
    Name: MyECSTaskRole
```

In my ecs_job_definitions.yaml file (nested tempalte), I am using this exported value.

```
Resources:
  AWSBatchJobDefinitionForNetPaymentApi:
  Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      JobDefinitionName:
        !Sub
        - "${TheAppNameForResources}-${TheEnvName}-job-def-net-pay"
        - TheAppNameForResources: !Ref AppNameForResources
          TheEnvName: !Ref EnvName
      ExecutionRoleArn:
        Fn::ImportValue: MyECSTaskExecutionRole
```

When the pipeline is executed, I am getting error "No export named MyECSTaskRole found"

Is this the right way of exporting/importing between templates?